# What happens when you access a file while it is being creating

Tags: http

I have a process that can update existing images on a web server, what happens when a client tries to access them while being editting, 404? Does it waits until editting is done? (it is pretty much instants, a couple kb only)

And what do you suggest if this is a wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens depends really on your OS. But in general I guess you will have a race condition. You can avoid that by using a lock mechanism (e.g.  [flock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking)) or using atomic file operations (e.g. move on the same FS is probably in your environment atomic):
Your process creates the new files somewhere in the same FS and **moves** them afterwards to existing file names.

Comment: Thank you, knowing mv is atomic will simplify this a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The specification for what happens when you try to access a file while it is being created depends on the operation system.

On Linux, if you are reading a file while it is being modified, you can technically read an intermediate state of the file. If you are making several modifications, you are guaranteed that the modifications will be done in order, but you might still see a modification that is partially complete.

In practice, what you are doing is fine, even for large files (because a large file would take a long time to be read, so you have time to finish saving the later parts of the file.

If you really want to be overly safe, you can copy the file to a temporary location, delete the old file, make the modifications, and then copy it back. You can still technically see an incomplete file, but a lot of file formats can be reasonably rendered even with data missing from the end (ie. if you delete a few lines from the bottom of a jpeg file, the image just loses it's bottom part -- it doesn't become entirely corrupted).

Comment: Use an atomic operation of your OS, e.g. move (in the same FS). Copy is on most OS not atomic!